# Is there any single word to express `make you understand`?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

Is there any single word to express `make you understand`?

I often face problem to replace the phrase `make you understand` when I say something to my audience like,

> "I did it to make you understand the purpose"

What can be the correct word?

Comment: maybe 'educate', or some synonym? "Make you understand" sounds a little aggressive. "Help you understand" sounds less so.

Comment: I suppose "pound it into your thick skull" doesn't qualify as a "single word".

Comment: Can you substitute *to make you understand* for something as simple as *to explain*?

Comment: In that particular sentence, I would use something like *demonstrate*, because of the verb *did*.

Comment: Trying to get you to [catch on (2)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/catch-on) to a casual way of saying it.

Comment: *Explain, convey, communicate, bring across* (yes that's a single word). General reference.

Comment: @Yosef afaik explain mostly used in verbal communication but the way to make someone understand is not limited to verbal stuff only right?

Comment: I don’t know why this post is closed in the name of off topic, I have added a tag single word request and this post is concisely asking so. If off topic why that particular tag is not being removed from the site?

Comment: No, most verbs that get over enough detail to give the listener understanding also work to do that for the reader: Explain, convey, communicate, bring across - per @RegDwigнt.

Comment: @RegDwigнt the post was closed as `off-topic`. I am confused why tag `single-word-requests` is not removed from this site. Could you please clarify why my post is not on topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like this one:

From https://www.dictionary.com/browse/elucidate

elucidate[ ih-loo-si-deyt ]

verb (used with object), e·lu·ci·dat·ed, e·lu·ci·dat·ing.
to make lucid or clear; throw light upon; explain

verb (used without object), e·lu·ci·dat·ed, e·lu·ci·dat·ing.
to provide clarification; explain.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work. Good first post.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but, I would tend to use:

- **Instill**

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/instill

> to put a feeling, idea, or principle gradually into someone's mind, so that it has a strong influence on the way that person thinks or behaves

And I'd modify your sentence thusly:

"I took your bike to instill in you that stealing is wrong"

Answer (score 1):

I would go with an alternate construction, to make it sound less aggressive.

***illuminate***

> to explain and show more clearly something that is difficult to understand

[Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/illuminate)

> I did that to illuminate the purpose.

***highlight***

> to attract attention to or emphasize something important

...also from [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/highlight). 
Synonyms include spotlight, emphasize etc

> I did that to emphasize/highlight the purpose.

NB: not sure if I would use 'purpose'

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this single word

> I did it to **enlighten** you as to the purpose.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/enlighten)

> **enlighten**
>   VERB
>
> **1** Give (someone) greater knowledge and understanding about a subject or situation.
>   *Thanks for educating and enlightening me.*

Comment: If educating and enlightening both are similar as many commented in this post, why both of them have been used in single example? Is there any real difference?